# Взаимодействие между узлами сети блокчейна

Tags: bitcoin, блокчейн

Как именно выглядит взаимодействие между узлами сети блокчейн? То есть, например мультиподпись модели 2 из 3: выбирается некоторая группа пользователей, как происходит подписание документа/транзакции? Каким образом решается, что именно эти 2 участника должны подписывать блок данных? Может есть какие-то полезные книги/статьи, которые рассказывают об этих тонкостях на уровне более углубленном, нежели чем поверхностное описание такой инфы на сайтах

Answer (score 0):

Это зависит от конкретного блокчейна. Например, в Hyperledger Fabric кто именно и для каких условий должен подписывать транзакцию определяется секьюрити-политикой чейн-кода при его деплое. Если в блокчейне используется консенсус BFT-группы при формировании блоков, типа Clique для Ethereum или IBFT для Quorum, то возможные подписанты и количество необходимых подписей задаются при настройке сети.